# Panning Algorithm following mouse Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, 2d

I have an algorithm that is frustratingly stubborn for the last 2 days. It's an algorithm that pans around a view. The code below implements the actual panning logic:

```
package com.next.plugin.designer.actions;

import com.next.plugin.designer.Canvas;
import com.next.plugin.designer.SketchDesigner;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class CanvasInteraction extends UserAction {


    private int startPanX, startPanY;

    @Override
    public void onExtendSketchDesigner(SketchDesigner sd) {

        Canvas canvas = sd.getCanvas();


        sd.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)){



               
                    canvas.viewX += (e.getX() - startPanX);
                    canvas.viewY += (e.getY() - startPanY);


                    startPanX = e.getX();
                    startPanY = e.getY();

                    sd.repaint();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)){
                    startPanX = e.getX();
                    startPanY = e.getY();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This class just draws the Rectangle at the pan offsets

```
package com.next.plugin.designer;

import java.awt.*;

public class Canvas {

    public int viewX = 0, viewY = 0;
    private int width = 640, height = 480;

    private BasicStroke basicStroke = new BasicStroke(3);



    public void draw(Graphics2D graphics2D) {


        graphics2D.setStroke(basicStroke);
        graphics2D.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        graphics2D.drawRect(viewX, viewY, width, height);
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure how to add videos on StackOverflow but the best description of the result is that the moment I start dragging (no matter where my mouse is), the rectangle in the above code just follows my mouse.

Thanks

Comment: [mcve] please..

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, I found the problem.

Don't try to register mousePressed events via MouseMotionListener, they aren't even called when the application runs. This caused the initial startPanX and startPanY to be 0, which simply added the location of the mouse onto the rect. Then all movements applied to viewX and viewY will simply make the rect follow the mouse.

No joke, I was fighting over this for 2 days, and after taking a break and sitting down, it hit me. That's programming for ya :^)